# Is there an equivalent to concat_ws in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have a ton of columns I am trying to aggregate together and most of them have NULL values. I want to separate values that do appear with a ';' but I cannot find an effective way to do this in oracle. CONCAT_WS would be exactly what I need as it would not add the delimeter between NULL values, but oracle does not support this.

```
concat_ws(';','dx89','dx90','dx91','dx92') as diagnoses3

ORA-00904: "CONCAT_WS": invalid identifier
```

Using a function like this is similar but doesn't quite get me what I need as you can see the ';' on the end of the string since dx91 and dx92 are NULL values:

```
dx89||';'||dx90||';'||dx91||';'||dx92 as diagnoses2

I63.8;I63.9;;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`NVL2()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2049.htm) function specific to Oracle DB together with pipe concatenation operators :

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING ';' 
               FROM dx89||NVL2(dx90,';'||dx90,dx90)||
                          NVL2(dx91,';'||dx91,dx91)||
                          NVL2(dx92,';'||dx92,dx92)) AS "Concatenated String"
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=482492c808723f739c5f71f54a7d80dd)</kbd>

Comment: This will insert a leading semicolon if `dx89` is null, though.

Comment: Exactly... Realised that I skipped the part after two years :). Thank you so much @JackDeeth

Comment: Oh, thank you - I did not know the `TRIM LEADING` syntax and this revision exactly solves my problem!

Comment: If one of the leading strings starts with `;` then this will remove that part of the string as well as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression to concatenate only the non-`NULL` values with leading delimiters and then remove only the initial delimiter:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
            CASE WHEN dx89 IS NOT NULL THEN ';'||dx89 END
         || CASE WHEN dx90 IS NOT NULL THEN ';'||dx90 END
         || CASE WHEN dx91 IS NOT NULL THEN ';'||dx91 END
         || CASE WHEN dx92 IS NOT NULL THEN ';'||dx92 END,
         2
       ) AS diagnoses2
FROM   table_name;
```

or

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
            NVL2(dx89, ';'||dx89, NULL)
         || NVL2(dx90, ';'||dx90, NULL)
         || NVL2(dx91, ';'||dx91, NULL)
         || NVL2(dx92, ';'||dx92, NULL),
         2
       ) AS diagnoses2
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(dx89, dx90, dx91, dx92) AS
  SELECT 'A',  'B',  NULL, 'D'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL, 'C',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A',  'B',  'C',  'D'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT ';;', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

| DIAGNOSES2 |
| --- |
| A;B;D |
| C |
| A;B;C;D |
| ;; |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hkx1b4Dc)

If, instead of using `SUBSTR`, you use `TRIM` and the first non-`NULL` value has the delimiter character as the first character(s) in the string then you will remove too many characters and the final row of the sample data would output `NULL`. Instead, it is better to remove only the number of characters in the delimiter using `SUBSTR`.