# Join strings in Oracle like concat_ws in SQL Server

Tags: sql, string, oracle, concatenation

I have a table with multiple string columns I would like to join together with a separator.

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d |
| a | b |  |  |
| a |  |  |  |

The result for that should be

```
'a-b-c-d'
'a-b'
'a'
```

In SQL Server I just do

```
select concat_ws('-', c1, c2, c3, c4) from my_table
```

In Oracle I can do

```
SELECT COALESCE(c1, '') || 
  CASE WHEN c2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '-' || c2 END || 
  CASE WHEN c3 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '-' || c3 END ||
  CASE WHEN c4 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '-' || c4 END  
FROM my_table
```

Is there a better solution in Oracle or even one that works for both - SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an equivalent to concat_ws in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103090/is-there-an-equivalent-to-concat-ws-in-oracle)

Comment: In terms of in both, unfortunately every dialect of SQL can be *very* different. For example even basic concatenation in T-SQL and PL/SQL is quite different, with them using `+` and `||` respectively. If you are working with multiple dialects, there are few times where you will have a query that is transferable without some kind of minimal change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version that works in both Oracle and SQL Server is tricky because the only string concatenation function available is `concat()` with two arguments.  But, you can do:

```
select trim('-' from
        concat(coalesce(c1, ''),
              concat(case when c2 is null then '' else concat('-', c2) end,
                     concat(case when c3 is null then '' else concat('-', c3) end,
                            case when c4 is null then '' else concat('-', c4) end
                           )
                    )
             ))
```

Here are the two db<>fiddles for [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4cf355b0a1882e1411ff57059ebd4c7) and [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e277e37a58c63fafc8e332d6234e04f).

Answer (score 1):

```
select c1 || nvl2(c2, '-'||c2,c2) || nvl2(c3, '-'||c3,c3) || nvl2(c4, '-'||c4,c4)
from mytable
```

test it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3d07b98e52c9cdc39f2ed9785a8ed796)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to

- concatenate all columns with `-` as a separator, and then
- remove double (triple, ...) `-` signs (with regexp) and
- remove leading/trailing `-` signs (with trim)

Something like this:

```
SQL> with test (c1, c2, c3, c4) as
  2    (select 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ,  'd' from dual union all
  3     select 'a' , 'b' , null, null from dual union all
  4     select 'a' , null, null, null from dual union all
  5     select 'a' , null, 'c' , null from dual union all
  6     select null, null, 'c' , 'd'  from dual
  7    )
  8  select
  9    c1, c2, c3, c4,
 10    --
 11    trim(both '-' from regexp_replace(c1 ||'-'|| c2 ||'-'|| c3 ||'-'|| c4, '-+', '-')) result
 12  from test;

C1 C2 C3 C4 RESULT
-- -- -- -- --------------------
a  b  c  d  a-b-c-d
a  b        a-b
a           a
a     c     a-c
      c  d  c-d

SQL>
```